# How do I resolve a React component into its elements before render?

Tags: reactjs

If I am given a React component of `<Nav />` and that component's `render()` method would yield a `<ul />` element with `<li />` elements nested inside of it, how would I resolve the React component into those elements?

My reason for doing so is to apply special BEM CSS class names to a component's element as well as any nested elements, all before being rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no direct way to do that and it's not encouraged. If your React component is supposed to be customized, it should expose property like cssClassName for container to pass in.

I can think of a possibly working hack that use [ReactDom.findDomNode](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode). Since you can only get the DOM after render is called, you need a container component with opacity 0 to render `<Nav/>`, then find the dom using RecatDom.findDomNode(), customize your css, then reset the container opacity 1.